# How to remove <i> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, tags

I use this script for my progress bars:

```
$('.progress-bars li').each(function(i){  
  var percent = $(this).find('.spann').attr('data-width');
  var $endNum = parseInt($(this).find('.spann strong i').text());
  var $that = $(this);

  $(this).find('.spann').animate({
    'width' : percent + '%'
  },1600, function(){
  });

  $(this).find('.spann strong').animate({
    'opacity' : 1
  },1400);  

  $(this).find('.spann strong i').countTo({
    from: 0,
    to: $endNum,
    speed: 1200,
    refreshInterval: 30,
    onComplete: function(){}
  });  

  if(percent == '100'){
    $that.find('.spann strong').addClass('full');
  }     
});
```

I use `<i></i>` tags to find the numbers for `countTo` functions. My problems is I want to delete these `<i>` tags after running `countTo` script.

Example:

```
<ul class="progress-bar"> 
    <li>
         <p>Video production</p>
         <div class="bar-wrap"><div class="spann" data-width="100"><strong><i>100</i>% </strong><div class="arrow"></div></div> </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
            <p>IOS Development</p>
            <div class="bar-wrap"><div class="spann" data-width="80"><strong><i>80</i>% </strong><div class="arrow"></div></div> </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After I run the script I want to remove `<i></i>` tags and keep the number.

Comment: Why not use something more semantic and not worry about removing them? Or include them in a `data-` attribute as well?

Comment: Because i use one page scroll and when i switch current page it start countTo again.
I was trying with a lot of things but this is my best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single line of code after calling your countTo script:

```js
$( "i" ).contents().unwrap();
```

This selects all the `<i>` tags. The `.contents()` gets the text inside `<i>`, and the `.unwrap()` deletes the content's parent which is the `<i>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var Is = document.querySelector(".progress-bar").querySelectorAll("i");
    Array.prototype.map.call(Is, function(element){
        var content = element.childNodes[0];
        element.parentNode.replaceChild(content, element);
    });
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar"> 
    <li>
         <p>Video production</p>
         <div class="bar-wrap"><div class="spann" data-width="100"><strong><i>100</i>% </strong><div class="arrow"></div></div> </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
            <p>IOS Development</p>
            <div class="bar-wrap"><div class="spann" data-width="80"><strong><i>80</i>% </strong><div class="arrow"></div></div> </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will search all `i`-elements within the progress bar, iterates over them and removes them, while appending the content to the `i`-element's parent.